# Visual Studio slow and unable to load dependencies

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2022 64-bit (version 17.1.0).

I experience problems to load/unload projects (very slow) and to load dependencies (fails).
It also takes long time (around 10 minutes?) to build (fails to build due to dependencies). Also slow (many minutes) to cancel the build.

[image: Not as administrator]

[image: Not as administrator]

But if I start the application as administrator, the build will happen successfully within seconds!

[image: As administrator]

How can this issue be fixed, other than starting it as administrator?

Thanks in advance!